# Can't link my files to my HTML(.htaccess)

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^modalidade/([0-9]+)/?$ /ver_modalidade.php?id_modalidade=$1 [NC,L]
```

My website was working properly until I did the last Rewrite rule. The last Rewrite "masks" the true URL, therefore I can't link my files.

I have my link files set like this:`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.ico">`

Is there a way to do this in .htaccess or do I need to indicate the full path to the file like: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{SERVER_NAME}/ico/favicon.ico">`

Answer (score 0):

If dose two RewiteRules are the only one that are in use, than your favicon issue is coming from somewhere else.

`ico/favicon.ico` is a relative path, so if the file is in `www.example.com/ico/favicon.ico` I would just change it to `/ico/favicon.ico`,
because if your load the page e.g. `/modalidade/123` the browser is looking in `/modalidade/ico/favicon.ico`

Adding the leading slash will prevent this.

Of course you could add a rewrite rule for the favicon as well but I'm not sure if that makes sense:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/ico/favicon\.ico$ /ico/favicon.ico [L]
```

Comment: I'm using $_SERVER vairables to link the files right, I just wanted to know if .htaccess had something to avoid this. BTW that solution would only apply to the "favicon" right?. Thanks

Comment: Yes this is one example for favicon. If you explain your file end folder structure in your question we maybe find some better solution